# Textsize between 'scriptsize' and 'tiny'

Tags: fontsize

Is there a way I can generate a textsize that is 50% of the way between scriptsize and tiny?

Could this be defined as a function to be used in the same way as \scriptsize or \tiny?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The file `size10.clo` associated with default 10pt font size contains

```
\newcommand\scriptsize{\@setfontsize\scriptsize\@viipt\@viiipt}
\newcommand\tiny{\@setfontsize\tiny\@vpt\@vipt}
```

Thus I would try in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\notsotiny{\@setfontsize\notsotiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\makeatother
```

Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\notsotiny{\@setfontsize\notsotiny\@vipt\@viipt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
ààà

\notsotiny ààà

\scriptsize ààà

\tiny ààà

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use this

```
\newcommand\notsotiny{\@setfontsize\notsotiny{6}{7}}
```

or even

```
\newcommand\notsotiny{\@setfontsize\notsotiny{6.31415}{7.1828}}
```

The second number is the baseline separation.

Comment: That's great, could you explain what the commands \@vpt \@vipt \@viipt \@viiipt mean? Is there a way to replace them with a numerical input into the function?

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I need :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Freeman, glad it helped. The `\@vpt` etc are simply macros expanding to  5, 6, 7, 8, but it becomes more complicated after that `\def\@xipt{10.95}`, `\def\@xviipt{17.28}` for example.

Comment: For me, \@vipt\@viipt yields the same font size as tiny; I need to use \@viipt\@viiipt to get a size in between tiny and scriptsize.